# How to add files to installer in InstallShield 5.1?

Tags: installshield

Yes, yes, I know that there are modern versions of InstallShield now, but I decided to tinker a bit and make the installer on version 5.1 (1996 or 98), but I still didn’t understand where to add files so that after the installer installs the files. Anyone can help me?